# error in running application on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written an app with XML and still I don't write Classes by java code.  But the emulator can show my app by its name and after that it says " unfortunately, app has stopped."  What I have to do for this problem??!

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Textview
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TextView2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you created the Android project, it usually creates some sort of MainActivity class even if you haven't written java code. There should be some Logcat output as to what happened, can you post that?

Comment: @Chad Campbell:   java.lang.classLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java.501) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:552) 
....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** have at least one activity (Java class) in your application so that manifest.xml could recognize that and run it.

Comment: Mr Ozturk could you please give me your email address? one address that I could send my code to you , really I have problem and I have nobody to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an activity to show this xml :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

As you can see your xml is called by the setContentView method.

This activity must be declared in your AndroidManifest.xml with

```
<activity
        android:name="YOURPACKAGE.ACTIVITY_NAME"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```